# GET API results to only 1 line instead of new line for each item

Tags: bash, shell

I'm building a bash script for accessing the yelp api v3 and export using CURL. However my results are returning only one line of results. I would like for each "id" to be on a new row/line. Here's the code thats not working

```
curl -X >> worked.csv GET -w 'name\n'  \
  "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=meats&location=san-mateo&price=1&sort_by=rating&DESC" \
  -H "authorization: " \
  -H "cache-control: no-cache" \
  -H "postman-token: ab6e8c01-ac37-bc8e-4baf-1eaddd493592"
```

and results are like

```
{"businesses": [{"id": "carrolls-meats-san-bruno-4"  "name": "Carroll's Meats"   "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/YXSjhk1LjemzLM8ORnH6Ug/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/carrolls-meats-san-bruno-4?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 209     "categories": [{"alias": "delis"    "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "salad"   "title": "Salad"}]  "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.630225   "longitude": -122.412556}   "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "189 San Bruno Ave W"  "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Bruno"     "zip_code": "94066"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["189 San Bruno Ave W"   "San Bruno  CA 94066"]}     "phone": "+16508718593"     "display_phone": "(650) 871-8593"   "distance": 12007.993205864}    {"id": "the-ravioli-house-san-mateo"    "name": "The Ravioli House"     "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/7N4_sUuCsHjwlMmnXWD1AQ/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-ravioli-house-san-mateo?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"   "review_count": 392     "categories": [{"alias": "delis"    "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "catering"    "title": "Caterers"}]   "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5640830993652    "longitude": -122.320419311523}     "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "505 S B St"   "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Mateo"     "zip_code": "94401"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["505 S B St"    "San Mateo  CA 94401"]}     "phone": "+16503447433"     "display_phone": "(650) 344-7433"   "distance": 1108.606250918}     {"id": "the-sandwich-spot-redwood-city-5"   "name": "The Sandwich Spot"     "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Id7DFC0t6bqZnIQr9qP3eQ/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-sandwich-spot-redwood-city-5?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"  "review_count": 623     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "hookah_bars"     "title": "Hookah Bars"}     {"alias": "newamerican"     "title": "American (New)"}]     "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.4864070738747    "longitude": -122.231816384113}     "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "2420 Broadway St"     "address2": null    "address3": ""  "city": "Redwood City"  "zip_code": "94063"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["2420 Broadway St"  "Redwood City   CA 94063"]}     "phone": "+16502991300"     "display_phone": "(650) 299-1300"   "distance": 10571.70939848}     {"id": "lorenzos-sandwich-shop-belmont"     "name": "Lorenzo's Sandwich Shop"   "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/AXRPqkJ6v5lCm58xGlvvSA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/lorenzos-sandwich-shop-belmont?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 343     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5127526153161    "longitude": -122.293408720031}     "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "911 Villa Ave"    "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Belmont"   "zip_code": "94002"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["911 Villa Ave"     "Belmont    CA 94002"]}     "phone": "+16505924321"     "display_phone": "(650) 592-4321"   "distance": 5090.5313565159995}     {"id": "takahashi-market-san-mateo"     "name": "Takahashi Market"  "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/fulLwbq-_82bvo2VZNxTPw/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/takahashi-market-san-mateo?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 505     "categories": [{"alias": "grocery"  "title": "Grocery"}]    "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.566842   "longitude": -122.320909}   "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "221 S Claremont St"   "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Mateo"     "zip_code": "94401"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["221 S Claremont St"    "San Mateo  CA 94401"]}     "phone": "+16503430394"     "display_phone": "(650) 343-0394"   "distance": 1396.4965773659999}     {"id": "mid-east-market-san-bruno"  "name": "Mid East Market"   "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/wAwXB8A_VlHFIsLxqM6AEw/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/mid-east-market-san-bruno?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"     "review_count": 119     "categories": [{"alias": "intlgrocery"  "title": "International Grocery"}]  "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.61506    "longitude": -122.40562}    "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "1776 El Camino Real"  "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Bruno"     "zip_code": "94066"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["1776 El Camino Real"   "San Bruno  CA 94066"]}     "phone": "+16508757100"     "display_phone": "(650) 875-7100"   "distance": 10439.216137762}    {"id": "eat-on-monday-mountain-view-3"  "name": "Eat On Monday"     "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/eNtpByJ9hwbpbyqWWgNKDA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/eat-on-monday-mountain-view-3?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"     "review_count": 164     "categories": [{"alias": "foodtrucks"   "title": "Food Trucks"}     {"alias": "catering"    "title": "Caterers"}]   "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.388427734375     "longitude": -122.075866699219}     "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": ""     "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Mountain View"     "zip_code": "94041"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["Mountain View  CA 94041"]}     "phone": "+14088130288"     "display_phone": "(408) 813-0288"   "distance": 28227.099396999994}     {"id": "grand-leader-market-san-bruno"  "name": "Grand Leader Market"   "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/IYHet-nbXDzETf1kI8hfGA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/grand-leader-market-san-bruno?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"     "review_count": 90  "categories": [{"alias": "delis"    "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "coffee"  "title": "Coffee & Tea"}]   "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.626651   "longitude": -122.4109783}  "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "600 San Mateo Ave"    "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Bruno"     "zip_code": "94066"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["600 San Mateo Ave"     "San Bruno  CA 94066"]}     "phone": "+16505892928"     "display_phone": "(650) 589-2928"   "distance": 11634.113107338}    {"id": "roma-deli-san-bruno"    "name": "Roma Deli"     "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/o8Y-YjVp0-oU9iZbnostGA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/roma-deli-san-bruno?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"   "review_count": 247     "categories": [{"alias": "italian"  "title": "Italian"}     {"alias": "delis"   "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.62214    "longitude": -122.41094}    "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "424 San Mateo Ave"    "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Bruno"     "zip_code": "94066"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["424 San Mateo Ave"     "San Bruno  CA 94066"]}     "phone": "+16505892360"     "display_phone": "(650) 589-2360"   "distance": 11295.457920863999}     {"id": "little-lucca-sandwich-shop-burlingame"  "name": "Little Lucca Sandwich Shop"    "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/nVuYW04zFKmF_yr8oGRpPg/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/little-lucca-sandwich-shop-burlingame?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"     "review_count": 790     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5941590204541    "longitude": -122.384402}   "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "Burlingame Shopping Plz"  "address2": ""  "address3": "1809 El Camino Real"   "city": "Burlingame"    "zip_code": "94010"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["Burlingame Shopping Plz"   "1809 El Camino Real"   "Burlingame     CA 94010"]}     "phone": "+16506978389"     "display_phone": "(650) 697-8389"   "distance": 7534.49696754}  {"id": "gracies-delectables-san-carlos"     "name": "Gracie's Delectables"  "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/0h6e-kELZgT6r3Kn4uG1dg/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/gracies-delectables-san-carlos?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 166     "categories": [{"alias": "delis"    "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5023264  "longitude": -122.2563865}  "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "902 Laurel St"    "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Carlos"    "zip_code": "94070"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["902 Laurel St"     "San Carlos     CA 94070"]}     "phone": "+16505954049"     "display_phone": "(650) 595-4049"   "distance": 7787.041842369999}  {"id": "green-valley-produce-market-san-bruno"  "name": "Green Valley Produce Market"   "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/IrRa7TLVY7evVWezBmvz1w/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/green-valley-produce-market-san-bruno?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"     "review_count": 88  "categories": [{"alias": "markets"  "title": "Fruits & Veggies"}    {"alias": "grocery"     "title": "Grocery"}     {"alias": "mediterranean"   "title": "Mediterranean"}]  "rating": 4.5   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.6295700073242    "longitude": -122.415550231934}     "transactions": ["delivery"     "pickup"]   "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "504 San Bruno Ave W"  "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "San Bruno"     "zip_code": "94066"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["504 San Bruno Ave W"   "San Bruno  CA 94066"]}     "phone": "+16502259027"     "display_phone": "(650) 225-9027"   "distance": 12152.16818284}     {"id": "bonne-sante-burlingame"     "name": "Bonne Sante"   "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/_XnPmufKiA0Zfu4KwhT0kQ/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/bonne-sante-burlingame?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 535     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "burgers"     "title": "Burgers"}     {"alias": "tradamerican"    "title": "American (Traditional)"}]     "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.58661    "longitude": -122.36469}    "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "1184 Broadway"    "address2": null    "address3": ""  "city": "Burlingame"    "zip_code": "94012"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["1184 Broadway"     "Burlingame     CA 94012"]}     "phone": "+16503421529"     "display_phone": "(650) 342-1529"   "distance": 5637.0513114}   {"id": "fare-pdq-belmont"   "name": "Fare   PDQ"    "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/njx8dlNiOpFLiwUxIHY-fQ/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/fare-pdq-belmont?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"  "review_count": 471     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "tradamerican"    "title": "American (Traditional)"}  {"alias": "hotdogs"     "title": "Fast Food"}]  "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5164058  "longitude": -122.2713519}  "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "1480 El Camino Real"  "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Belmont"   "zip_code": "94002"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["1480 El Camino Real"   "Belmont    CA 94002"]}     "phone": "+16505953273"     "display_phone": "(650) 595-3273"   "distance": 5756.736800661999}  {"id": "americano-deli-and-grill-san-mateo"     "name": "Americano Deli & Grill"    "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/BOsNQbxfnOgHXHuhM_7D9Q/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/americano-deli-and-grill-san-mateo?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 262     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "delis"   "title": "Delis"}]  "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.54097    "longitude": -122.29099}    "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "224 E Hillsdale Blvd"     "address2": null    "address3": ""  "city": "San Mateo"     "zip_code": "94403"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["224 E Hillsdale Blvd"  "San Mateo  CA 94403"]}     "phone": "+16502120500"     "display_phone": "(650) 212-0500"   "distance": 2604.71759467}  {"id": "chavez-supermarket-and-taqueria-redwood-city-2"     "name": "Chavez Supermarket & Taqueria"     "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ArimTcNjSxfyUpOr4m6LcA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/chavez-supermarket-and-taqueria-redwood-city-2?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 170     "categories": [{"alias": "grocery"  "title": "Grocery"}     {"alias": "mexican"     "title": "Mexican"}]    "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.4885509  "longitude": -122.2353577}  "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "775 Arguello St"  "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Redwood City"  "zip_code": "94063"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["775 Arguello St"   "Redwood City   CA 94063"]}     "phone": "+16503678819"     "display_phone": "(650) 367-8819"   "distance": 10184.08778943}     {"id": "leonardos-italian-deli-and-cafe-millbrae"   "name": "Leonardo's Italian Deli & Cafe"    "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/5SNjXM48EGwYbcM2z7KW7Q/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/leonardos-italian-deli-and-cafe-millbrae?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"  "review_count": 160     "categories": [{"alias": "delis"    "title": "Delis"}   {"alias": "coffee"  "title": "Coffee & Tea"}    {"alias": "italian"     "title": "Italian"}]    "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.60319    "longitude": -122.39444}    "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "540 Broadway"     "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Millbrae"  "zip_code": "94030"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["540 Broadway"  "Millbrae   CA 94030"]}     "phone": "+16506979779"     "display_phone": "(650) 697-9779"   "distance": 8782.386767438}     {"id": "ikes-lair-of-redwood-city-redwood-city-2"   "name": "Ike's Lair of Redwood City"    "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/cQ8HkW_Rd5RYsYp2L8-BOA/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/ikes-lair-of-redwood-city-redwood-city-2?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"  "review_count": 543     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}  {"alias": "delis"   "title": "Delis"}]  "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.4861346  "longitude": -122.2342516}  "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "2655 Broadway St"     "address2": ""  "address3": ""  "city": "Redwood City"  "zip_code": "94063"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["2655 Broadway St"  "Redwood City   CA 94063"]}     "phone": "+16503652200"     "display_phone": "(650) 365-2200"   "distance": 10447.842361096}    {"id": "the-habit-burger-grill-san-mateo"   "name": "The Habit Burger Grill"    "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/wdJC9EzmfvkrHyLXot_-Kg/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-habit-burger-grill-san-mateo?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"  "review_count": 446     "categories": [{"alias": "burgers"  "title": "Burgers"}     {"alias": "sandwiches"  "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.544952   "longitude": -122.291011}   "transactions": []  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "1100 Park Pl"     "address2": "Ste 20"    "address3": ""  "city": "San Mateo"     "zip_code": "94403"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["1100 Park Pl"  "Ste 20"    "San Mateo  CA 94403"]}     "phone": "+16502869944"     "display_phone": "(650) 286-9944"   "distance": 2356.3877422339997}     {"id": "ikes-place-san-mateo-5"     "name": "Ike's Place"   "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/b_c_xWsR7t5wZwf5guC_zQ/o.jpg"     "is_closed": false  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/ikes-place-san-mateo-5?adjust_creative=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=TRh56Tszp1lUJualdVr-6w"    "review_count": 278     "categories": [{"alias": "sandwiches"   "title": "Sandwiches"}]     "rating": 4.0   "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.5674163928038    "longitude": -122.31955400788}  "transactions": ["pickup"]  "price": "$"    "location": {"address1": "680 E 3rd Ave"    "address2": null    "address3": ""  "city": "San Mateo"     "zip_code": "94401"     "country": "US"     "state": "CA"   "display_address": ["680 E 3rd Ave"     "San Mateo  CA 94401"]}     "phone": "+16503758900"     "display_phone": "(650) 375-8900"   "distance": 1421.655389586}]    "total": 40     "region": {"center": {"latitude": 37.558179800000005    "longitude": -122.3236981420565}}}id
```

What is the best way to go about fixing this? I'm fairly new so I could be missing something very basic.

Comment: Why are you putting JSON data into a CSV file?

Comment: Generally I wouldn't however the person im trying to do this for requests CSV. So I will be resulting one json file and one CSV. just not sure how to handle the CSV part.

Comment: ...You use a tool that can convert the JSON into a proper CSV file...

Comment: take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271307/post-json-data-with-curl-from-a-while-loop-bash-shell

Comment: Thats what I would like to do but automatically from the command line. so that I can then email the files without having to manually change anything. unless you mean something that will work through shell.

Answer (score 1):

Should try a JSON parsing application ([json](http://trentm.com/json/) or [jq](http://list.xmodulo.com/jq.html)) and pipe curl result to it:

```
curl ... | json businesses | json -a -d, id name >> worked.csv
```

That will print all ids, one per line.

Comment: I just edited the answer with more detail. But please, remove your token from the call. If not anybody will be able to execute calls with your account.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't have python so getting this to run didnt work. but turned me onto a different result that did.

Thank you for catching that authorization!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gonzalo-matheu for turning me onto a different way of getting this finished.

I ended up using sed and stripping it. which resulted nicely, after some excel work. Here's the end.

```
curl -X >> worked.csv GET  \
  "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=meats&location=san-mateo&price=1&sort_by=rating&DESC" \
  -H "authorization: Bearer (AUTH_CODE)" \
  -H "cache-control: no-cache" \
  -H "postman-token: ab6e8c01-ac37-bc8e-4baf-1eaddd493592"
cat worked.csv | sed -r 's/\<id\>/\n/g;s/://g;s/"//g' > worked.csv
```